# Django List Displays Out of Order

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I have a django list that I use `{% regroup ranked_matches by rank as ranked_matches %}` to sort in the template however there is one value that is always out of order. I've gone into the db and changed it several times however this value is always out of order. Can anyone shed any light as to what might be causing this?

Also I realize I've posted very little code, I'm not sure what is relevant here. Thanks.

EDIT:

I just noticed I'm having a similar issue but here the alphabetical sort for another list is off for only one value. I've gone into the django admin and if I try sorting by the column in question it sorts properly there. This makes me believe that it is not an issue with the value stored in the db.

Comment: Is this value a field in your model? Is it a `BooleanField`, `CharField`, etc. or a related field like `ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 2):

`{% regroup ... %}` will organize lists by your grouper, but it will not sort the resulting list by the grouper.

If you have a list of dictionaries, consider using the `dictsort` filter together with the `regroup` tag.

Otherwise, your can first `regroup` your list, then sort using `dictsort`, and finally `regroup` again. The second `regroup` will need a grouper that can handle the output generated by the first `regroup`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#grouping-on-other-properties

Comment: Or just sort in your view rather than your template.